# accessing an image in a theme directory from a link tag

Tags: asp.net, themes, skinning

I have a link tag which assignes a bookmark icon to the page:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/App_Themes/Default/images/bookmark.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

Currently, it's hard coded to the Default theme, but I want it to change based on the theme that is applied to the web app.  How can I point to the current theme directory?

Comment: How is your app handling the theme?  Is it a value in session?

Comment: @Sonny Boy - no, it uses the ASP.NET skinning functionality, so the theme is specified in the web config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.Theme returns the string property of the currecntly selected theme. You need to assemble the href Attribute yourself using string operations.